# In VXML is there a way to re-enter a field from a filled block without clearing the nomatch/noinput counters?

Tags: vxml, avaya

I am having an issue with a VXML form, basically I have a field with an initial prompt and have a set of noinput nomatch blocks using counters to play back different prompts dependent on the number of noinput/nomatch events have been thrown.

I need to report on each attempt so the ASR confidence is set pretty low and in the filled element I check the confidence level and from that I would like to either accept, reprompt if confidence is low or if confidence is borderline, play a confirmation prompt. The issue I am having is that in the filled block I am performing an action to check the confidence and if too low I do the following (field name is collection):

```
<clear namelist="collection"/>
<throw event="nomatch"/>
```

The issue is that this clears the nomatch/noinput counters but I need these to remain. If I remove the clear tag, the nomatch event is hit but as the field is still 'filled' it doesn't accept input.

Is there a way to re-enter the field from the filled block without clearing the counters or is there a way I can access the counters via ECMA script to set them again or something similar? Can I only clear certain values from the "collection" field so the filled element is not immediately re-entered but retains the counters?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this - the simple solution was to move the nomatch noinput event handlers out of the collection field scope to the document scope - this meant that when I called clear on the collection field, the noinput and nomatch counters were not cleared

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue, it is the standard :
https://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml5.3.3

> "In addition, if the variable name corresponds to a form item, then
>   the form item's prompt counter and event counters are reset."

You can add your own counter with a variable. Increment in the process block and test the value with  or the attribute "cond" for the prompts.